# Cannot authenticate to Docker in Elastic Beanstalk through S3

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, amazon-s3, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/create_deploy_docker_image.html#docker-singlecontainer-dockerrun-privaterepo

Following the instructions here to connect to a private docker hub container from Elastic Beanstalk, but it stubbornly refuses to work. It seems like when calling `docker login` in Docker 1.12 the resulting file has no email property, but it sounds like aws expects it so I create a file called dockercfg.json that looks like this:

```
{
    "https://index.docker.io/v1/": {
        "auth": "Y2...Fz",
        "email": "c...n@gmail.com"
    }
}
```

The relevant piece of my Dockerrun.aws.json file looks like this:

```
  "Authentication": {
    "Bucket": "elasticbeanstalk-us-west-2-9...4",
    "Key": "dockercfg.json"
  },
```

And I have the file uploaded at the root of the S3 bucket. Why do I still get errors that say `Error: image c...6/w...t:23 not found. Check snapshot logs for details.` I am sure the names are right and that this would work if it was a public repository. The full error is below. I am deploying from GitHub with Circle CI if it makes a difference, happy to provide any other information needed.

```
INFO: Deploying new version to instance(s).                         
WARN: Failed to pull Docker image c...6/w...t:23, retrying...
ERROR: Failed to pull Docker image c...6/w...t:23: Pulling repository docker.io/c...6/w...t
Error: image c...6/w...t:23 not found. Check snapshot logs for details.
ERROR: [Instance: i-06b66f5121d8d23c3] Command failed on instance. Return code: 1 Output: (TRUNCATED)...b-project
Error: image c...6/w...t:23 not found
Failed to pull Docker image c...6/w...t:23: Pulling repository docker.io/c...6/w...t
Error: image c...6/w...t:23 not found. Check snapshot logs for details. 
Hook /opt/elasticbeanstalk/hooks/appdeploy/pre/03build.sh failed. For more detail, check /var/log/eb-activity.log using console or EB CLI.
INFO: Command execution completed on all instances. Summary: [Successful: 0, Failed: 1].
ERROR: Unsuccessful command execution on instance id(s) 'i-06b66f5121d8d23c3'. Aborting the operation.
ERROR: Failed to deploy application.                                

ERROR: Failed to deploy application.
```

EDIT: Here's the full Dockerrun file. Note that %BUILD_NUM% is just an int, I can verify that works.

```
{
  "AWSEBDockerrunVersion": "1",
  "Authentication": {
    "Bucket": "elasticbeanstalk-us-west-2-9...4",
    "Key": "dockercfg.json"
  },
  "Image": {
    "Name": "c...6/w...t:%BUILD_NUM%",
    "Update": "true"
  },
  "Ports": [
    {
      "ContainerPort": "8080"
    }
  ]
}
```

EDIT: Also, I have verified that this works if I make this Docker Hub container public.

Comment: Could you post the whole Dockerrun.aws.json file?

Comment: Yep thanks, just did

Comment: Everything seems to be correct. Could you confirm that EB has all required IAM permissions to access that S3 bucket?

Comment: Double checked, the user I'm using the access key for has full S3 access and full Elastic Beanstalk access

Comment: `Check snapshot logs for details` what's in it then?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

OK, let's do this;

Looking at the same doc page,

> With Docker version 1.6.2 and earlier, the docker login command creates the authentication file in ~/.dockercfg in the following format:

```
{
  "server" :
  {
    "auth" : "auth_token",
    "email" : "email"
  }
}
```

You already got this part correct I see. Please double check the cases below one by one;

1) Are you hosting the S3 bucket in the same region?

> The Amazon S3 bucket must be hosted in the same region as the
>   environment that is using it. Elastic Beanstalk cannot download files
>   from an Amazon S3 bucket hosted in other regions.

2) Have you checked the required permissions?

> Grant permissions for the s3:GetObject operation to the IAM role in
>   the instance profile. For details, see [Managing Elastic Beanstalk
>   Instance Profiles](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/iam-instanceprofile.html).

3) Have you got your S3 bucket info in your config file? (I think you got this too)

> Include the Amazon S3 bucket information in the `Authentication` (v1) or
>   `authentication` (v2) parameter in your `Dockerrun.aws.json` file.

Can't see your permissions or your env region, so please double check those.
If that does not work, i'd upgrade to Docker 1.7+ if possible and use the corresponding `~/.docker/config.json` style.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions, sadly I made the stupid mistake of having 2 Dockerrun.aws.json files and editing the wrong one, since I was getting auth issues no matter what I never actually double checked that. All resolved now.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your Docker version, this file is saved as either ***~/.dockercfg*** or ***~/.docker/config.json**

> cat ~/.docker/config.json

Output:

```json
{
  "auths": {
    "https://index.docker.io/v1/": {
      "auth": "zq212MzEXAMPLE7o6T25Dk0i"
    }
  }
}
```

***Important:***

Newer versions of Docker create a configuration file as shown above with ***an outer auths object***. ***The Amazon ECS agent only supports dockercfg authentication data that is in the below format, without the auths object***. If you have the jq utility installed, you can extract this data with the following command:

> cat ~/.docker/config.json | jq .auths

Output:

```json
{
  "https://index.docker.io/v1/": {
    "auth": "zq212MzEXAMPLE7o6T25Dk0i",
    "email": "email@example.com"
  }
}
```

1. Create a file called `my-dockercfg` using the above content.
2. Upload the file into the S3 bucket with the specified key(`my-dockercfg`) in the Dockerrun.aws.json file.

```json
{
  "AWSEBDockerrunVersion": 2,
  "authentication": {
    "bucket": "elasticbeanstalk-us-west-2-618148269374",
    "key": "my-dockercfg"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're upgrading Elastic Beanstalk Platform version then you need to change the Docker credentials file format (the credentials file that is uploaded in your S3 bucket)

OLD format

```
{
    "server" :
    {
      "auth" : "auth_token",
      "email" : "email"
    }
}
```

NEW Format

```
{
    "auths":{
      "server":{
        "auth":"key"
      }
    }
}
```

The "key" in the new format is identical to the "auth_token" in old format. Only the JSON structure has changed a little plus explicit "email" key is not required anymore.